# Which design pattern allows to get this architecture

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, architecture

I have the following objects :

- Formula
- Stock
- Counter
- etc ...

all these objects are called indicators and have common properties (Id, Name, Value...).
Each entity has its own properties:

- Formula: FormulaExpression, FormulaCode, OperandsList ...
- Stock: StockValue, StockLimit...
- Counter: CounterIndex...
- etc ...

So logically, i have to make indicator class containing the common properties, and for each entity i have to create a class that inherits from indicator.

Formula is a special indicator that can contain any type of indicators. The formula's indicators are named operands.

the operand object has the following properties:
operandId, operandCode, operandIndex

when i want to list the formula operands, i want to get objects which inherit from indicator, operand and entity type (create an object that have indicators properties, operand properties and stock properties for example)

which design pattern or which architecture allows me to have this behaviour?

---

To explain more the problem

The entities (`Formula`, `stock`, `Counter`..) are `Indicators` and not necessary `Operands`, `Operands` are `Indicators` too. Object `Indicator` is the primitive type of entities, we can create an  `Indicator` and then decorate it to become a `Formula` for example and than decorate it to become an `Operand` when it is added to another `Formula`.

Comment: Can a `Formula` indicator contain another `Formula` indicator in its list of operands?

Comment: yes, Formula can contain any type of indicator, even Formula type

Comment: Please bear in mind that in no way stating that a "design pattern allows one to get an architecture" makes any kind of sense.lol

Comment: So did you find a way to achieve what you needed?

Comment: Solution given by dogiordano seems to be right, I am trying to improve it by removing the use of generic type.

Answer (score 0):

What I posted here may looks like a lot of code but it's actually very straightforward.

Most of the properties and constructors are there to simplify the script in the main function.

The base concept is to create a [Generic Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the operands that contains a reference to the base `Indicator` object it's created from.

Test this code in an empty project and it'll be very easy to understand from the output.

```cs
class Indicator{
    // Common properties
}
class Counter : Indicator{
    public int CounterIndex;
    public Counter(int cI){
        CounterIndex = cI;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CounterIndex: {0}", CounterIndex);
    }
}
class Operand{
    // Common operand properties
}
class Operand<T> : Operand{
    public T BaseIndicator;
    public Operand(T bI){
        BaseIndicator = bI;
    }
}
class Formula : Indicator{
    public string FormulaExpression;
    public int FormulaCode;
    public List<Operand> OperandsList = new List<Operand>();

    public Formula(string fE, int fC){
        FormulaExpression = fE;
        FormulaCode = fC;
    }

    public void Print ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("FormulaExpression: {0}; FormulaCode: {1}",
                           FormulaExpression, FormulaCode);
        if (OperandsList.Count == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Operands: ");
        foreach(Operand o in OperandsList){
            if(o is Operand<Counter>){
                Operand<Counter> cO = o as Operand<Counter>;
                cO.BaseIndicator.Print();
            }else if(o is Operand<Formula>){
                Operand<Formula> fO = o as Operand<Formula>;
                fO.BaseIndicator.Print();
            }else{
                // I'ts a simple Indicator
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End Operands");
    }
}
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Counter c1 = new Counter(2);
        Counter c2 = new Counter(3);
        Formula f1 = new Formula("a + b", 7);
        Formula f2 = new Formula("a * b", 10);

        Formula f = new Formula("a ^ b", 32);
        f.OperandsList.Add(new Operand<Counter>(c1));
        f.OperandsList.Add(new Operand<Formula>(f1));
        f.OperandsList.Add(new Operand<Counter>(c2));
        f.OperandsList.Add(new Operand<Formula>(f2));
        f.Print();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Operand is an object that have its owen properties ( operandId, operandCode, operandIndex). The problem is at run time objects can be an  Indicator, and a Formula (or Stock or ...), and an  Operand.

Comment: If you use Indicator as the base class for Operand and Operand as the base class for Stock, Counter, Formula ecc... you can get the operand's type at runtime as in the answer.

Comment: Stock, Counter, Formula are not necessary Operand, they just can be an indicator, I want to decorate the Indicator to become Formula or a Stock, and then decorate it again to become an Operand. Do you think that your solution can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to use an expando object that is filled by each operand using **polymorphic dispatch**. The expando object lets you add custom properties, and the polymorphic dispatch lets you close your code against operands change.

You would start by using a base class for the Operand that contains your basic elements

```
public abstract class Operand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public dynamic BuildObject()
    {
        dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
        o.Id = Id;
        o.Name = Name;
        AddPropertiesToObject(o);
        return o;
    }

    protected internal abstract void AddPropertiesToObject(dynamic o);
}
```

Then adding a new Operand type is very easy since you can control what you will add to it independently:

```
public class Stock : Operand
{
    public double StockValue { get; set; }

    protected internal override void AddPropertiesToObject(dynamic o)
    {
        // I decided to ignore the base class Id and Name
        // adding them would be trivial, but may not be what you need since 
        // it would overwrite the base values...
        // To add them you would have to wrap this virtual method call with
        // a call to a function doing the insertion in the base class 
        o.StockValue = StockValue;
    }
}
```

The `Formula` object would simply iterate on the contained operands and call their `AddPropertiesToObject` in turn (of course it can also add its own data but for the example I didn't include any)

```
public class Formula : Operand
{
    public List<Operand> InnerOperands { get; set; }

    protected internal override void AddPropertiesToObject(dynamic o)
    {
        foreach (var op in InnerOperands)
        {
            op.AddPropertiesToObject(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but project is running under framework 3.5 :(

Comment: The principle can be tweaked anyway. You could store the values in a key value dictionnary, or in any way you desire. The important thing is that you don't need to know the type of an operand to call the method that will work on the object you want to return

Comment: As I understand your solution, entities inherit from Operand object, and get properties values from database using `AddProperitiesToObject` method. The question now is that entities (`Formula`, `stock`, `Counter`..) are `Indicators` and not necessary `Operands`, `Operands` are `Indicators` too. Object `Indicator` is the primitive type of entities, we can create an  `Indicator` and then decorate it to become a `Formula` for example and than decorate it to become an `Operand` when it is added to another `Formula`. So inheritance from`Operand` is not the best way to describe object.

Comment: I misunderstood what the base class was, but you can transpose what i suggested by renaming the `Operand` base class to a `Indicator` base class. You would have `Operand` inheriting from `Indicator`, and would plug you concrete classes at the right level